# How to write an IIS redirect rule and preserve parts of the original URL?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I need to create an IIS rule to redirect all URLs of this form:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/articles/article-name
```

to this form

```
http://www.example.com/bar/articles/article-name
```

Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. Using a regex to catch the name of the article in the original URL, I can use that captured group as a parameter in the redirected URL, like this:

```
<rule name="foo/articles/article-name/" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^foo/articles/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="bar/articles/{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

So I take the name of the article and use it as {R:1}, meaning the first captured group.
If I were to have two regex expressions, for an URL like `/foo/articles/article-name/article-id`, I would do something like this:

```
<rule name="foo/articles/article-name/" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^foo/articles/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="bar/articles/{R:1}/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```